# Change file owner in Windows

Tags: c, windows, filesystems, file-management

Is there an API in Windows similar to Linux's [chown](http://google.com/search?q=man+2+chown)?

Comment: The Windows security model isn't really based around file ownership the way UNIX file systems are, so this isn't really a tool that is needed very often.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=70562

```
    // #includes omitted for the sake of sanity
    HANDLE token;
    char *filename = "somefile.txt";
    char *newuser = "someuser";
    DWORD len;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR security = NULL;
    PSID sidPtr = NULL;
    int retValue = 1;

    // Get the privileges you need
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &token)) {
        SetPrivilege(token, "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege", 1);
        SetPrivilege(token, "SeSecurityPrivilege", 1);
        SetPrivilege(token, "SeBackupPrivilege", 1);
        SetPrivilege(token, "SeRestorePrivilege", 1);
    } else retValue = 0;

    // Create the security descriptor
    if (retValue) {
        GetFileSecurity(filename, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, security, 0, &len);
        security = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)malloc(len);
        if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(security, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
            retValue = 0;
    }

    // Get the sid for the username
    if (retValue) {
        char domainbuf[4096];
        DWORD sidSize = 0;
        DWORD bufSize = 4096;
        SID_NAME_USE sidUse;
        LookupAccountName(NULL, newuser, sidPtr, &sidSize, domainbuf, &bufSize, &sidUse);
        sid = (PSID)malloc(sidSize);
        if (!LookupAccountName(NULL, string, (PSID)sid, &sidSize, domainbuf, &bufSize, &sidUse))
            retValue = 0;
        }
    }

    // Set the sid to be the new owner
    if (retValue && !SetSecurityDescriptorOwner(security, sidPtr, 0))
        retValue = 0;

    // Save the security descriptor
    if (retValue)
        retValue = SetFileSecurity(filename, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, security);
    if (security) free(security);
    if (sid) free(sid);
    return retValue;
```

`

Comment: Holy hell, all that to replace a simple `chown` call!

Comment: Did you omit the function return type, name, and parameters for the sake of vaguery?

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [cacls or icacls commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) useful... They're not exactly straightforward to use though

Can you provide a bit more information on what you're trying to do?